# onChange event for React child component to update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to learn how to implement a React form (ES6 syntax) and pass the onChange events for each field up to a controller parent component which is responsible for updating the state. This works fine for standard html elements, however I am trying a pre-canned Datepicker (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-date-picker) for a date field and can't readily pass the event back up to the parent in the same way. Is there a simple way to address this?

**Controller Component**

```
   class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {job: ''} 
    }

    setJobState(event) {
        var field = event.target.name;
        var value = event.target.value;
        this.state.job[field] = value;
        this.setState({job: this.state.job});
    }


    render () {
        return <Child onChange={this.setJobState.bind(this)} />
    }
}
```

**Child Component**

```
class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);

    }

    render () {
        <form>
         <input type="text" name="jobNumber" onChange={this.props.onChange} /> 
         <DatePicker name="dateCmmenced" onChange={this.props.onChange}  />
        </form>
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're binding the `onChange` handler correctly, but the `onChange` handler for the `DatePicker` is called with two parameters: `value` and `formattedValue` (see here: https://github.com/pushtell/react-bootstrap-date-picker#datepicker-).  In your `Child` component just set different handlers for the two `onChange` events, that are able to handle the difference in arguments.

Comment: I'll give that a try and see if I can get it to work. Thanks.

Comment: Also be careful how you update the state. `this.state.job[field] = value` is not how you should update your state. Always make state changes by calling `this.setState`.

Comment: Based on the parameters from the `DatePicker` component, the best I could come up with was the following, but I am a js novice, so yeah:     `setJobState(event) {

        if (typeof event === 'object') {
            var field = event.target.name;
            var value = event.target.value;
            this.state.job[field] = value;

        }
        else if (typeof event === 'string') {
            this.state.job.dateCommenced = event;
        }

        
        return this.setState({ job: this.state.job });

    }`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The `onChange` handler for the `DatePicker` is not called with a standard browser `change` event, but with `value` and `formattedValue` as arguments. I would recommend to register different `onChange` handlers in your `Child` component that transform the respective input field's event:

**Controller Component**

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {} 
    }

    onChange(field, value) {
        // parent class change handler is always called with field name and value
        this.setState({[field]: value});
    }


    render () {
        return <Child onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} />
    }
}
```

**Child Component**

```
class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
    }

    onFieldChange(event) {
        // for a regular input field, read field name and value from the event
        const fieldName = event.target.name;
        const fieldValue = event.target.value;
        this.props.onChange(fieldName, fieldValue);
    }

    onDateChange(dateValue) {
        // for a date field, the value is passed into the change handler
        this.props.onChange('dateCommenced', dateValue);
    }

    render () {
        return <form>
          <input type="text" name="jobNumber" onChange={this.onFieldChange.bind(this)} /> 
          <DatePicker onChange={this.onDateChange.bind(this)}  />
        </form>
    }
}
```

Comment: Just what I've been looking for! 1+

Comment: how to call onChange event after load input?

Answer (score 3):

```js
import React from 'react'
export default {
  [formData, setFormData] = React.useState({
    name: '',
    number: '',
    email: '',
    address: '',
    zip: ''
  })

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <input type='text' name='name' onChange={handleChange} />
      <input type='text' name='number' onChange={handleChange} />
      <input type='email' name='email' onChange={handleChange} />
      <textarea name='address' onChange={handleChange}></textarea>
      <input type='text' name='zip' onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```