# On iOS React text/number input is stuck forcing user to enter in phone number

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, input, mobile-safari

In my React/NextJS app, I have this simple input:

Components:

> Search > SearchSelect > ExchangeInfo.tsx:

**Search.tsx**

```
<SearchSelect
  assets={assets}
  selected={selected}
  exchange={exchange}
  exchanges={exchanges}
  fetching={fetching}
  aggregate={aggregate}
  checkAggregate={this.handleCheckAggregate}
  enterPosition={this.handleEnterPosition}
  exchangeSelect={this.handleExchangeSelect}
/>

//... the function:

@bind
handleEnterPosition(position: number) {
  this.setState({ position })
}
```

**SearchSelect**

```
<SearchExchanges
  selected={selected}
  exchange={exchange}
  exchanges={exchanges}
  checkAggregate={checkAggregate}
  aggregate={aggregate}
  enterPosition={this.props.enterPosition}
  exchangeSelect={this.props.exchangeSelect}
/>
```

**ExchangeInfo**

```
import React from 'react'
import { bind } from 'decko'

import { IAsset, IMarketAsset } from '../../shared/types'
import { EnterPositionStyle } from '../../styles'

interface IPropsInfo {
  asset: IAsset
}

interface IPropsCount {
  exchanges: IMarketAsset[]
}

interface IPropsPosition {
  asset: IAsset
  enterPosition(position: number): void
}

export const ExchangeSelectInfo = (props: IPropsInfo) =>
  <h2>Exchanges with <span>{props.asset.currency}</span> denominated in BTC, ETH, USD, USDC, or USDT will be listed above. Otherwise the asset's price will be an aggregate of supported exchanges.</h2>

export const ExchangesCount = (props: IPropsCount) => {
  const { exchanges } = props
  const pural = exchanges.length > 1 && 's'
  return (<option key={'default'}>({exchanges.length}) Exchange{pural}:</option>)
}

export class EnterPosition extends React.Component<IPropsPosition> {
  render() {
    const { asset } = this.props
    return (
      <EnterPositionStyle>
        <h2>Enter your <span>{asset.currency}</span> position in order to add asset to your Portfolio. Or add the asset to your Watchlist.</h2>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Position" onChange={this.handleChange} />
      </EnterPositionStyle>
    )
  }

  @bind
  private handleChange(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement
    const parsed = parseFloat(target.value)
    const position = Number.isNaN(parsed) ? 0 : parsed
    console.log('target.value', target.value);
    this.props.enterPosition(position)
  }
}
```

It works on the web fine: https://moon.holdings (Or https://dev.moon.holdings) (Click on the + select an asset, then Aggregate then try to enter in position.

However on mobile it only lets me put in an actual phone number, and typing does not change the input :(

### UPDATE

Seems that it's an iPhone issue, my Android friends can add in positions, but not my iPhone ones. Strange....

### UPDATE

I added an input to the root component / container and it works... seems like the problem is that the input I'm using is embedded 3 components down. Or something related to that.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: So what does `handleSearchTyping` look like?

Comment: @GProst just added it!

Comment: I have one guess that for some reason in iOS Safari React marks the input as 'controlled' if you provide `onChange` handler even if you don't provide `value` prop. So React doesn't update the input value on input change automatically.
I can't currently check that theory, so I believe you can check if input starts working once you remove the `onChange` handler?

Comment: Oh it's because I'm passing the handler down period.. hmm the only input that works on Mobile is one where the handler is in the same file... ugh ok I may have to resort to using Redux for the other inputs, which kinda sucks... doesn't make sense. Maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40795906/onchange-event-for-react-child-component-to-update-state

Comment: Wow ok that did not fix it, enterPosition was moved 2 components down, I changed it so that the input's onChange would exist in the same component and just passing the number up 2 components to it's parent. Will try again later, if that fails may have to attempt with redux, or possibly change the component structure when on smaller browser widths.

Comment: Have you tried not using `type="number"` and manually validating the entry?

Comment: @Deckerz yes tried that... :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Believe it or not, this is a css problem. Saw your page, you have these css on inputs that cause problem in safari.

```
user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
```

Remove them, and your inputs will get back to work. In case you have difficulty removing them, override with

```
-webkit-user-select: text;
user-select: text;
```

Comment: Solution tested on iOS simulator, fixed. In fact, the same problem also affects desktop Safari.

Comment: OMG thanks! That was it! :D Was starting to think this was unfixable...

Comment: @LeonGaban no pb, you know css, [it's easy](https://m.imgur.com/t/developer/ei0FQVH)

Comment: thanks so much! thought i have to show a message: "please use another browser" *lol

Comment: ^ `*:not(input, textarea){ user-select:none; }` to exclude input/textarea would suffice.

Comment: OMG! I spent 5 days on this problem. I never mess with standard rules Ounnecessarily again.