# How to retrieve a react component value

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make my own custom input[type='text'] on React, with my own effects.

To do that, I created my component:
**Textbox.js**

```
import React from "react";

class Textbox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      inputValue: props.value,
      fieldActive: false,
      label: props.label,
      placeholder: props.placeholder,
      type: props.type,
      maxLength: props.maxLength,
      error: false,
      required: props.required,
      inputChange: props.onChange,
      id: props.id,
      valid: !props.required,
      submitted: props.submitted,
      _value: props.value,
      updated: false
    };
    //console.log(this.props);

    this.updateInputValue = this.updateInputValue.bind(this);
    this.activateField = this.activateField.bind(this);
    this.disableFocus = this.disableFocus.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
      fieldActive: (nextProps.value != ''),
      inputValue: nextProps.value
    });
  }

  componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    //console.log(nextState.inputValue);

    if(/*this.state.inputValue != this.props.value*/ this.props.value != '' && !this.state.updated ){
      this.setState({
        inputValue: nextProps.value,//this.props.value,
        updated: true,
        fieldActive: true
      });
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    //console.log('updating value: ' + prevProps.submitted);
    if (this.props.submitted !== undefined) {
      if (this.props.submitted !== prevProps.submitted) {
        if(!this.state.required) return;
        this.setState({
          error: this.state.required && this.state.inputValue == ""
        });
      }
    }
  }

  activateField() {
    this.setState({
      fieldActive: true
    });
  }

  disableFocus(e) {
    if (e.target.value == "") {

      this.setState({
        fieldActive: false,
        error: this.state.required,
        valid: !this.state.required
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        error: false
      });
      if (this.state.type == "email") {
        this.setState({
          error: !/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z]+$/.test(e.target.value)
        });
      }
    }
  }

  updateInputValue(e) {
    //console.log('writing: ' + e.target.value);
    this.setState({
      inputValue: e.target.value,
      submitted: false,

    });
    //this.props.value = e.target.value

    if (this.state.inputChange != undefined && this.state.inputChange != null)
      this.state.inputChange(e.target.id, e.target.value, this.state.valid);

    this.activateField(e);
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="form-group field-group">
        <label
          htmlFor=""
          className={
            this.state.fieldActive
              ? this.state.error
                ? "field-active form-label floating error"
                : "field-active form-label floating"
              : "form-label floating hide"
          }
        >
          {this.props.label}
        </label>
        <input
          className={
            this.state.error
              ? "form-input floating-label error"
              : "form-input floating-label"
          }
          type={this.props.type}
          placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
          maxLength={this.props.maxLength}
          value={this.state.inputValue}
          name={this.props.id}
          id={this.props.id}
          autoComplete="off"
          onFocus={this.activateField}
          onBlur={this.disableFocus}
          onChange={this.updateInputValue}
        />
        <label
          className={this.state.error ? "error" : "error hide"}
          style={{ fontSize: 14, fontWeight: 400 }}
        >
          You must complete this field
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Textbox;
```

**myjsfile.js**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clients: [],
      client: {
        name: "",

      },

    };
//... More methods and properties

    <Textbox
                      label="Client name"
                      placeholder="Client name / Customer"
                      id="name"
                      type="text"
                      required={true}
                      value={this.state.client.name}
                      maxLength="20"
                      //onChange={this.handleChange}
                      submitted={this.state.submitted}
                    />
```

In my file, I'm using `Textbox` as a component, but each time that I want to retrieve the value inside the `Textbox` I get `empty`.

What am I doing wrong? Why the value is not updating? How can I solve it?

Comment: what do you mean by `retrieve the value inside the Textbox`, are you not getting prop in there?

Comment: Any sandbox? And there are a lot of `==` which seems odd.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onChange event for React child component to update state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40795906/onchange-event-for-react-child-component-to-update-state)

Comment: Also, `componentWillReceiveProps` is UNSAFE

Comment: @Rikin I'm thinking they mean that client.name in the parent component never updates. They could move the onChange handler to the parent and pass it to the Textbox component so the parent state is updated with the value.