# Control sibling component from parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a page with REACT and I have the Parent Component which contains 2 child components.

```
class Page extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <SubmitButton>
            <ResetButton>
            <Form />
        );
    }
}

class Form extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
                <Grid container spacing={3}>
                    <Grid item xs={3}>
                        <TextField
                            fullWidth
                            label="Name"
                            name="name"
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            value={data.name}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                    ...
                </Grid>
        );
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do reset or submit the values of the form. I've read that I need to control the state of the children(form) from the parent, but how do I do that? I don't want to use refs. 
Maybe it's not a proper design but the buttons have to be outside of the Form component. Is it bettor to use uncontrolled components instead of controlled in this case? I'm new to React so any help is welcome.

EDIT: The answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40795906/onchange-event-for-react-child-component-to-update-state) really helped me to understand the proper approach.

Comment: Have you tried the react-form?

Comment: Yes, but I would rather not use it. This question is more about how to make different components communicate with each other rather than using library components.

Comment: Then you can use the redux. To pass the value from child to parent and their will a store In which you can empty the field and also submit the form based on the Type and Payload

Answer (score 1):

Need to set a state in the parent and pass data to the child as props. Changes in state  will trigger a re-render of the React component.
I have given a simple example of reset button.

```
class Page extends Component {
  state = {
    name: "someString"
  };

  render() {
    const { name } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <SubmitButton> </SubmitButton>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ name: "" })}> </button>
        <Form data={name}> </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
class Form extends Component {

render() {
const {data} = this.props;
    return (
            <Grid container spacing={3}>
                <Grid item xs={3}>
                    <TextField
                        fullWidth
                        label="Name"
                        name="name"
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        value={data}
                    />
                </Grid>
                 </Grid>

    );
}
```

I also recommend you to see some React tutorials about states. Even the offical docs have great explanations about this topic
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Read this about state
https://medium.com/the-andela-way/understanding-the-fundamentals-of-state-in-react-79c711be677f

Comment: Thank you. Your answer and the one I linked in my question really helped me.