# I can't get results from onChange on a React Typescript component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, onchange

I'm using [the React Color lib](https://casesandberg.github.io/react-color/) to create a custom component in my application. My child component is composed by two components of React Colors: CirclePicker and ChromePicker. Both share the *colorPicker* state variable as value. So, if one change his value, the other will change too.

As you can see on my Child Component, I put one invisible input that shares the same *colorPicker* value (I don't know if it's the right wat to do it). And my goal here is: when the input change, I could do something, for example: *alert('COLOR CHANGED')* (this is on my code in *handleOnChange* function)

**Child component:**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { CirclePicker, ChromePicker } from 'react-color';
import { Icon } from './../Icon/Icon';
import './color-picker.scss';

export interface ColorPickerProps {
  onChange: (value: string) => void;
}

export function ColorPicker(props: ColorPickerProps) {
  const [colorPicker, showColorPicker] = React.useState(false);
  const [finalColor, changeColor] = React.useState('#fff');
  function handleOnChange() {
    alert('COLOR CHANGED');
    props.onChange(finalColor);
  }
  return (
    <div className="relative-position">
      <input type="text" value={finalColor} onChange={() => handleOnChange} style={{display: "none"}}/>
      <CirclePicker
        color={finalColor}
        onChangeComplete={colore => changeColor(colore.hex)}
        colors={[
          '#004de8',
          '#2ecc71',
          '#ff9300',
          '#62708b',
          '#ff003a',
          '#20396a'
        ]}
        circleSize={24}
      ></CirclePicker>
      <a
        className="btn-select-color"
        onClick={() => showColorPicker(!colorPicker)}
      >
        <Icon viewIcone="ArrowDropDown" style={{ margin: '5px' }} />
      </a>
      {colorPicker ? (
        <span className="chrome-picker">
          <ChromePicker
            color={finalColor}
            onChangeComplete={colore => changeColor(colore.hex)}
            disableAlpha={true}
          />
        </span>
      ) : (
        ''
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Situations:**

I've tried more or less how they've explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40795906/onchange-event-for-react-child-component-to-update-state), but no matter what I do, the *handleOnChange* function is not called and I can't see the alert.

Furthermore, my goal is to use this component in parent, more or less like this:
**Parent component: **

```js
<ColorPicker onChange={e => this.state.color = e} />
```

So, on this way, I could have on parent state the color picked.

I can't get nothing in the Child function, neither having the state updated on the parent component.

Could someone help me? I'm a new user of React :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

The input's value is linked to state. So when state changes, the value changes. BUT, no event was fired on the input. You were trying to use a react [event handler](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) on an input that wasn't firing any events; meaning `handleOnChange` never got called so `props.onChange` never got called...

### Solution

Use [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) to listen for when the input's value/state value changes. If you use [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref), you can stop your `props.onChange` from running when the component mounts. Check out the [DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-hermann-3g6g0).

```
import * as React from "react";
import { FunctionComponent, useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { CirclePicker, ChromePicker } from "react-color";

const colors = [
  "#004de8",
  "#2ecc71",
  "#ff9300",
  "#62708b",
  "#ff003a",
  "#20396a"
];

export interface ColorPickerProps {
  onChange: (value: string) => void;
}

const ColorPicker: FunctionComponent<ColorPickerProps> = ({ onChange }) => {
  const [colorPicker, showColorPicker] = useState(false);
  const [finalColor, changeColor] = useState("#fff");
  const componentMounted = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (componentMounted.current) {
      componentMounted.current = false;
      console.log(
        "Don't run props.onChange when the component mounts with useRef"
      );
    } else {
      onChange(finalColor);
      alert("finalColor changed via useEffect");
    }
    return () => undefined;
  }, [finalColor]);

  return (
    <div className="relative-position">
      <input type="text" value={finalColor} style={{ display: "none" }} />
      <CirclePicker
        color={finalColor}
        onChangeComplete={colore => changeColor(colore.hex)}
        colors={colors}
        circleSize={24}
      />
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => showColorPicker(!colorPicker)}>click me</button>
      {colorPicker && (
        <span className="chrome-picker">
          <ChromePicker
            color={finalColor}
            onChangeComplete={colore => changeColor(colore.hex)}
            disableAlpha={true}
          />
        </span>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(
  <ColorPicker
    onChange={() => {
      console.log("onChange");
    }}
  />,
  rootElement
);
```

Comment: Hi @Ari, your solution worked perfectly. Could you help me understand what I did wrong that stopped the prop onChange?

Comment: Happy to help! Added an explanation to the answer. Please accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`useCallback` may be a good option, refer to this [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57289811/function-inside-functional-component-in-react-hooks-performance), and [document](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { CirclePicker, ChromePicker } from "react-color";

import "./styles.css";

function App(props) {
  const [colorPicker, showColorPicker] = React.useState(false);
  const [finalColor, changeColor] = React.useState("#fff");

  const handleColorChange = React.useCallback(console.log("Work via callback"));
  return (
    <div className="relative-position">
      <input value={finalColor} onChange={console.log("Work directly")} />
      <input value={finalColor} onChange={handleColorChange} />
      <CirclePicker
        color={finalColor}
        onChangeComplete={colore => changeColor(colore.hex)}
        colors={[
          "#004de8",
          "#2ecc71",
          "#ff9300",
          "#62708b",
          "#ff003a",
          "#20396a"
        ]}
        circleSize={24}
      />
      {colorPicker ? (
        <span className="chrome-picker">
          <ChromePicker
            color={finalColor}
            onChangeComplete={colore => changeColor(colore.hex)}
            disableAlpha={true}
          />
        </span>
      ) : (
        ""
      )}
      <p>{finalColor}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit silly-rgb-lf7k6]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's strange, on my application doesn't work neither directly nor via callback.

Comment: @VítorResende checkout the online example, and remember to check the console in your browser.

Comment: I'm checking the console and you're right, the online example on CodeSandbox is working. I'll check carefully my app, thanks!